# How to adjust division inside division with min-height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created following html code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="main-body">
       <section id="post-section">
       </section>
     </section>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#wrapper
{
margin:0 auto;
width:1000px;
min-height:600px;

}
#main-body
{
width:100%;
min-height:1000px;
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:10px;
}
 #post-section
{
float:left;
width:800px;
min-height:1100px;
border-right:1px solid gray;
background:plum;
}
```

Problem is due to min-height of "main-body" size of wrapper is increasing but due to "post-section" size of "wrapper" and "main-body" is not increasing.

Comment: What do you want to do?? You din't mention what you are trying to make?

Comment: Your "wrapper" has min-height:600px and "post-section" has 1100px. Looks like a misfit.

Comment: I want to increase wrapper and main-body size when I increase size of post-section but somehow it is not happening.

Comment: In that case set "height:auto;" for both "wrapper" and "main-body".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 'clearfix'. Add this css rule:

```
main-body:after {
    content: ".";
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EM77F/2/

Comment: Thanks it worked but I didn't understand it properly basically content: "."; , what is it for?

Comment: @VivekKumar Here is a good explanation of clearfix: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: @VivekKumar Actually this is a better site: http://www.jqui.net/tips-tricks/css-clearfix/  The idea is that you need an invisible block element without float to make the containing element recognize the height.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `float: left` on your `#post-section`.

SOLUTION 1:

Drop the float: left. But you probably need it (otherwise it wouldn't be there).

SOLUTION 2:

Add `overflow: auto` to `#main-content`, that way the browser will know that there are floating items to consider. And the box will expand. Note that you'll need to adjust the width's to min-width or accept a horizontal scrollbar

SOLUTION 3

Add a clearing br after `#post-section`:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="main-body">
        <section id="post-section">
        </section>
    <br style="clear: both;" />
    </section>
</div>
```